# How to copy cells to another sheet using IF AND Macro?

Tags: excel, if-statement, copy, new-operator, worksheet

I would like to copy some specific columns if criterias are met. 
Namely if the value in row 4 is "Fælles" and the text is NOT bold.

Please take a look at my code and tell me what i do wrong.
I don't have much experience with coding or VBA.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

A = Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 34 To A

Next
If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i,4).Value = "Fælles" Then
    Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then
    Worksheetss("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Worksheets("Stig Okt").Activate


End Sub
```

No error occours, but it doesn't really do anything and i don't understand why?

Comment: You loop but don't do anything in the loop. `Next` is where the loop ends. Use F8 and step through the code and see what the code does and you will learn what is the issues.

Comment: Also properly indented code will make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, i will read about this idented! :)

Comment: Thanks for the F8 tip. It seems as if the code jumps whenever i put in the AND function! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is the way your code is supposed to be.
I moved the `Next` to after the ifs that way your code should work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

A = Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 34 To A
    If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i,4).Value = "Fælles" Then
        Worksheets("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    If Worksheets("Stig Okt").Cells(i, 4).Font.Bold = False And Cells(i, 4).Value = "Lagt ud" Then
        Worksheetss("Stig Okt").Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Laura Okt").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next
Worksheets("Stig Okt").Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: You, sir. Are my new hero! Thank you so much!!